# Generate Private key for SSL Certificate to be used inside Docker Container

Tags: django, docker, ssl, tls1.2, traefik

I'm working on a project that runs Docker and has 3 containers:

- Django
- PostgreSQL
- traefik
  Now I'm going to generate a private key to add an SSL certificate to my website, the question is where should I generate private key?
  Inside the main server that running the Docker?
  or inside the Django container?
  or inside Traefik container?
  I'm using **trafik:alpine** for trafik & **python:3.6-alpine** for Django
  if it is the container where I should generate a private key,
  What is the command line should I use inside container to generate a private key?
  Actually I have built private.key and certification.crt files referenced them inside traefik.toml file and i got this error:

```
failed to load X509 key pair: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input
```

That's why I think the problem is with my private.key which I generated inside the main server not inside any container.

Here is the configuration i use inside **traefik.toml** file if you want to know more information:

```
logLevel = "INFO"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
# Entrypoints, http and https
[entryPoints]
  # http should be redirected to https
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  # https is the default
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
    [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "/certs/ new_cert_v2.chained.crt"
    keyFile = "/certs/hrattendence_gs-group_nl.key"
    
[file]
[backends]
  [backends.django]
    [backends.django.servers.server1]
      url = "http://django:5000"
[frontends]
  [frontends.django]
    backend = "django"
    passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.django.headers]
      HostsProxyHeaders = ['X-CSRFToken']
    [frontends.django.routes.dr1]
      rule = "Host:IP here"
```

And here is the Full error message:

```
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration file /etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="No tls.defaultCertificate given for https: using the first item in tls.certificates as a fallback."
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.7.16 built on 2019-09-13_01:12:20PM"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#collected-data\n"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=error msg="failed to load X509 key pair: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:0xc000b04b40 Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc0008fba60} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Preparing server https &{Address::443 TLS:0xc0007797a0 Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc0008fba80} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=error msg="Unable to add a certificate to the entryPoint \"https\" : unable to generate TLS certificate : tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Starting provider configuration.ProviderAggregator {}"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :443"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *file.Provider {\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":0,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Directory\":\"\",\"TraefikFile\":\"/etc/traefik/traefik.toml\"}"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=error msg="failed to load X509 key pair: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
traefik_1_623bf12389b8 | time="2020-09-19T14:24:35Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :443"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should generate the TLS certificate and private key outside of Docker, using whatever tool you would normally.  This could be the `openssl` command-line tool, or a hosted tool like Amazon's Certificate Manager, or LetsEncrypt, or a broader credential-management tool like Hashicorp's Vault.  You probably do not have the tools to create and correctly sign the certificate inside your image, and that's okay.

Once you have the (signed) certificate and private key, you can use a Docker bind mount to inject them into the container when you start it.  For example, if you're using Docker Compose to launch the three containers, and you have the PEM file and private key in the same directory, you can set

```yaml
services:
  traefik:
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/certs
```

to mount the `certs` subdirectory of the current directory into `/certs` in the container.

Comment: should I convert .crt file into PEM file?